# jurko/suds: Type not found error even when it exists in wsdl and while printing client object

Tags: web-services, python-3.x, wsdl, suds

jurko/suds: The type exists in wsdl and the client when its created. However, when the client.factory.create function is called, the type not found error is raised. Please help if someone knows where I'm going wrong. I even tried by saving the wsdl file locally, but the same error is raised.

Version: suds-0.6 python3.5.1

```
from suds.client import Client
client = Client("http://netconnect.bluedart.com/Demo/ShippingAPI/Waybill/WayBillGeneration.svc?wsdl")
print(client)
Suds ( https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ )  version: 0.6

Service ( WayBillGeneration ) tns="http://tempuri.org/"
   Prefixes (5)
      ns0 = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SAPI.Entities.Admin"
      ns1 = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SAPI.Entities.Enums.AWBGeneration"
      ns2 = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SAPI.Entities.WayBillGeneration"
      ns3 = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"
      ns4 = "http://tempuri.org/"
   Ports (2):
      (BasicHttpBinding_IWayBillGeneration)
         Methods (2):
            GenerateWayBill(ns2:WayBillGenerationRequest Request, ns0:UserProfile Profile)
            ImportData(ns2:ArrayOfWayBillGenerationRequest Request, ns0:UserProfile Profile)
         Types (17):
            ns2:ArrayOfDimension
            ns2:ArrayOfWayBillGenerationRequest
            ns2:ArrayOfWayBillGenerationResponse
            ns2:ArrayOfWayBillGenerationStatus
            ns2:CommodityDetail
            ns2:Consignee
            ns2:Dimension
            ns1:ProductType
            ns2:Services
            ns2:Shipper
            ns0:UserProfile
            ns2:WayBillGenerationRequest
            ns2:WayBillGenerationResponse
            ns2:WayBillGenerationStatus
            ns3:char
            ns3:duration
            ns3:guid
      (WSHttpBinding_IWayBillGeneration)
         Methods (2):
            GenerateWayBill(ns2:WayBillGenerationRequest Request, ns0:UserProfile Profile)
            ImportData(ns2:ArrayOfWayBillGenerationRequest Request, ns0:UserProfile Profile)
         Types (17):
            ns2:ArrayOfDimension
            ns2:ArrayOfWayBillGenerationRequest
            ns2:ArrayOfWayBillGenerationResponse
            ns2:ArrayOfWayBillGenerationStatus
            ns2:CommodityDetail
            ns2:Consignee
            ns2:Dimension
            ns1:ProductType
            ns2:Services
            ns2:Shipper
            ns0:UserProfile
            ns2:WayBillGenerationRequest
            ns2:WayBillGenerationResponse
            ns2:WayBillGenerationStatus
            ns3:char
            ns3:duration
            ns3:guid

request = client.factory.create('WayBillGenerationRequest')
(WayBillGenerationRequest) not-found
path: "WayBillGenerationRequest", not-found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/vatsalshah/Developer/virtualenvs/bluedart_python351/lib/python3.5/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 218, in create
    raise TypeNotFound(name)
suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: 'WayBillGenerationRequest'
```

Answer (score 0):

Including the namespace before the type resolved the issue. For e.g., for the above error:
Changing request = client.factory.create('WayBillGenerationRequest') to request = client.factory.create('ns2:WayBillGenerationRequest') resolved the error.